# Match some part of string separated by delimiter

Tags: ruby, regex

I [sic] strings like:

```
xx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx
th-asd-welcome-ruk-23
name-lastname-hello
```

I want to match the second set of characters that are delimited with a hyphen, for example: `xxx`, `asd`, `lastname`.

I tried:

- `^(?:[^-]+-){1}([^-]+)`, which matches `xx-xxx`
- `(?<=-)[^\-].+(?=-)`, which matches `xxx-xxxxx-xxx`

How do I just match the second octet?

Comment: Assuming s denotes your string, can't you just `s.split('-')[1]` ?

Comment: Please add comments for downvotes so people know what they did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't necessarily the right way to go about doing this. First I'd simplify the task:

```
STRINGS = %w[
  xx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx
  th-asd-welcome-ruk-23
  name-lastname-hello
]

STRINGS.map { |s| s.split('-')[1] }
# => ["xxx", "asd", "lastname"]
```

That splits the string on hyphens into arrays and returns the second item found in each array.

Then I'd use a pattern in conjunction with `scan` to find only what is wanted:

```
STRINGS.map { |s| s.scan(/[^-]+/)[1] }
# => ["xxx", "asd", "lastname"]
```

That finds all sub-strings that are *NOT* hyphens.

Regular expressions are great for some things, but can increase problems with maintenance, sometimes way beyond their value. They can also slow code remarkably, simply because they're not very smart, and adding that intelligence requires a lot of testing and knowledge of what the engine is going to do. So, go there carefully, and test/benchmark so you know if the pattern, and path, is fast. I've written a lot of code, and mentored a lot of developers, and found a lot of places where they used a pattern wrong, introduced hard to detect bugs or slowed loops dramatically. I'm a big believer in benchmarking and testing multiple paths.

For instance:

```
require 'fruity'

STRINGS = %w[
  xx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx
  th-asd-welcome-ruk-23
  name-lastname-hello
]

compare do
  split { STRINGS.map { |s| s.split('-')[1] } }
  scan { STRINGS.map { |s| s.scan(/[^-]+/)[1] } }
end
# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> split is faster than scan by 4x ± 0.1
```

From experience I knew that `split` would run faster than using `scan` with a pattern.

From experience I also know that patterns can be extremely fast. Testing variations of patterns and extracting the records:

```
require 'fruity'

STRINGS = %w[
  xx-xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xx
  th-asd-welcome-ruk-23
  name-lastname-hello
]

compare do
  split { STRINGS.map { |s| s.split('-')[1] } }
  scan { STRINGS.map { |s| s.scan(/[^-]+/)[1] } }
  slice { STRINGS.map { |s| s[/^(?:[^-]+)-([^-]+)/, 1] } }

  stribizhev { STRINGS.map { |s| s.match(/(?<=-)[^-]+(?=-)/)[0] } }
end
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> slice is faster than split by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
# >> split is faster than stribizhev by 1.9x ± 0.1
# >> stribizhev is faster than scan by 80.0% ± 10.0%
```

So, *THAT* is what you should do to determine the path to follow. Then you weigh the maintenance cost: Is it easier to maintain `s.split('-')[1]` or `s[/^(?:[^-]+)-([^-]+)/, 1]`?

And, the reason the last pattern outruns the simple `split` which is extremely fast, is because the pattern is anchored. Anchoring patterns gives the engine an incredibly useful hint about how to locate the pattern desired which it uses to its advantage. It also doesn't need any backtracking, which wastes the engine's CPU time, and instead the engine can continue looking forward to find what it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the dot and use of following regex :

```
(?<=-)[^\-]+(?=-)
```

Or instead of using look-around use a capture group :

```
-([^\-]+)-
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/#pcre)

Comment: Damn. I tried your first one and Rubular.com showed it not working. Turns out that Rubular.com is somewhat misleading and your first one works.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your patterns are too greedy. `[^-]+` and `.+` will just consume as many characters as possible. Mind that `[^\-].+` does not mean "any number of character other than hyphen". This means "match 1 non-hyphen, and then any characters, as many as possible".

A simple `/(?<=-)[^-]+(?=-)/` with `match` can do this trick:

```
puts "th-asd-welcome-ruk-23".match(/(?<=-)[^-]+(?=-)/)
```

Or go simple (without regex):

```
puts "th-asd-welcome-ruk-23".split("-")[1]
```

Output:

```
asd
```

See [TutorialsPoint demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbUU4QVByVlpJYlE)